# Update label text tcl during runtime

Tags: tcl

I have a gui that has a label which I would like to have text change based on the section of the test that is being performed.  However, it doesn't change immediately but waits for the user input (i.e. messageBox).  But I want it to automatically update.  Is there anyway this can happen?

I tried using configure which changes the text but it doesn't happen as soon as the line of code is encountered.  Do I need to focus on the label first and then unfocus?  If so, how do I use the focus command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `update idletasks` after you have configured the new text.

Comment: It's a good idea to not wait _too_ long before processing events; things like window resizes or user focus changes require events to be handled correctly. (Yes, getting that right can take quite a bit of work to do well.)